# Can't find Microsoft SQL Server even if it is installed?

Tags: sql-server

Regarding the following images, I have obviously installed the Microsoft SQL Server, but I can't find the exe-file or anything named Microsoft SQL Server in the start menu.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Anyone who knows what to do to solve this, or do I need to install something more?

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server Management studio in order to perform task on server?

Comment: Have you tried by launch it using command prompt [sqlservr.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180965(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: No SQL Server Management, I only installed Visual Studio. I tried to run it that way, but it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server runs as a service. You can start and stop it from windows services. SSMS is a gui tool for managing ddl (creating and altering tables and index's for example) and dml (writing queries to inquire, update or add data to databases).SSMS comes free with every edition of SQL server - perhaps you didn't tick a box when installing? You can also do this stuff the old fashioned way using sqlcmd from command line(DBAs love this for some reason) but for us mortals SSMS is much less of a struggle. As an aside there are other guis such as Toad (expensive) and Heidisql (free) amongst others which will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have the engine. What you've got to do now is install SQL Server Management Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: I only installed Visual Studio, I thought it was enough. So I need to downlooad and install the file you linked to as well?

Comment: SSMS is the application that gives you access to your SQL Server engine that you may have installed with VS, so if you want to utilize the engine (use it to make databases, query them, etc.) then yes, you do need SSMS installed.

Comment: Okej, thank you, I will try this. After the installation, how do I run the SQL Server?

Comment: You just run the SQL Server Management Studio. You'll have it displayed in your start menu, the icon looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/wGKTDgk.png

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the various SQL Server components that are installed by Visual Studio (recent version) or SQL Server Data Tools (as used by VS).

Comment: I have only installed Visual Studio actually, maybe it's not enough? Do I need to make a clean installation of the SQL Server itself?

Comment: Okej, what do I need install to get the SQL Server? Is it enough with Server Management Studio?

Comment: Do you want the full db engine locally (how about integration services etc.)? If yes then you'll need the full install. (LocalDB is not the full SQL Server, but a cut down version to run per application.) NB. as of 2016, SSMS is a separate install to the server installer.

Comment: I see, thank you. SSMS is needed to be separately installed anyway, no matter what version of the SQL Server I use?

Comment: Explaining the possible options for SQL Server installs and their interaction with VS is beyond the scope of a [SO] answer let alone a comment. SSMS keys: it is installable with or without the SQL Server services; prior to 2016 it was all one installer (select different options), but in 2016 it is now a separate installer.